# Change nav title link in docusaurus

Tags: configuration, docusaurus

In my docusaurus.config.js file I have the following which defines the contents of my nav bar:

```js
    navbar: {
      title: 'Utili Documentation',
      logo: {
        alt: 'Utili Logo',
        src: 'https://file.utili.xyz/UtiliSmall.png',
      },
      items: [
        {
          href: 'https://utili.xyz/',
          label: 'Utili',
          position: 'right',
        },
        {
          href: 'https://github.com/230Daniel/UtiliDocs/',
          label: 'GitHub',
          position: 'right',
        },
      ],
    },
```

I would like to change the link of the navbar title from https://docs.utili.xyz/ to https://docs.utili.xyz/docs. How could I do so? I've tried adding a href value, but when building I was told that it was invalid.

I'm using Docusaurus 2.

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party, but [documentation](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/themes/configuration#navbar-title--logo) actually shows the correct way, altough it may be a bit puzzleling. The trick is to set the `href` field of the `logo` attribute. That field is in fact binded to the link of the title itself (altough the title href cannot be directly set). Citing the documentation, he solution thus may be

```
      logo: {
        alt: 'Utili Logo',
        src: 'https://file.utili.xyz/UtiliSmall.png'
        href: 'https://docs.utili.xyz/docs', // Default to `siteConfig.baseUrl`.
        target: '_self', // By default, this value is calculated based on the `href` attribute (the external link will open in a new tab, all others in the current one).
      },
```

How one can set the title without displaying a logo, that I do not know.